# Passing an instance of DirectoryIterator to another script via exec() is not working as expected

Tags: php, file, iterator, exec

I have a page that is executing a script for each file in a directory:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('/var/www/OCR3/upload_pending/');

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    exec("php manual_doc_proccessor.php $fileinfo");
    echo "php manual_doc_proccessor.php $fileinfo" . " Sent for proccessing <BR>";
}
```

Going to this script:

```
$fileinfo = $argv[1];
if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
    print_r($fileinfo->getFilename()) . PHP_EOL ;
    $fileName = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    echo $fileName;
}
```

However when the script runs I get the error:

> Call to a member function isDot() on a non-object

I am expecting each iteration of the script to echo the file name, but instead i get the error.

What am I missing and how can I get this to process the files correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you pass `$fileinfo` in a string to the other script it's no longer an instance of [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), because the magic method [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.tostring.php) is called, which converts it to the filename itself. So you don't need and can't use `isDot()` or `getFilename()`, just make a simple if statement like this:

```
$fileinfo = $argv[1];
if ($fileinfo != "." && $fileinfo != "..") {
    print_r($fileinfo) . PHP_EOL ;
    $fileName = $fileinfo;
    echo $fileName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This got me going in the right direction.